# core dump in a multithread program

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, pthreads, coredump

i was trying to write a simple multithreaded program. It is dumping the core. I have my function that is called when a thread is created below:

```
void *BusyWork(void *t)
{
   int i;
   int *tid;
   int result=0;
   tid = t;

   printf("Thread %d starting...\n",*tid);
   for (i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
       result = result + (i* i);
   }
   printf("thread %d is sleeping for %d sec's\n",tid,tid);
   sleep(tid);
   printf("Thread %d done. Result = %e\n",tid, result);
   pthread_exit((void*) t);
}
```

My call to pthread_create function is below inside the main function:

```
int t;

for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) 
{
      printf("Main: creating thread %d\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&thread[t], &attr, BusyWork, (void *)t);
}
```

Please help me in finding where is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
printf("Thread %d starting...\n",*tid);
```

You can achieve what you want with:

```
printf("Thread %d starting...\n",(int) t);
```

or
    printf("Thread %d starting...\n", tid);

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with this line:

```
printf("thread %d is sleeping...
```

All of the references to `tid` should be `*tid`.

Comment: hi paul...could you please also explain why?

Comment: Because tid is not an integer, but a pointer to an integer.  C being so tolerant as it is of integer-like types, you may actually get an output value, but it wont be a nice friendly integer like 4 or 7, but some 32-bit memory address that *points* to a 4 or a 7.  Since your thread process does not modify the value pointed to by this pointer, I would suggest changing your declaration of tid from `int *tid` to `int tid`, and assign to it using `tid = *t;`  Now it is just a plain ol' friendly integer.  None of this explains why you are getting a core dump though.

Comment: Wow, my C debugging skills *are* rusty!  You are passing the int *value* t from the main function, but dereferencing it as an int *pointer*.  t has the values from 0 to NUM_THREADS-1, so as soon as your thread tries to deref tid in the first printf, it blows up.  Make the change I suggested in my answer, but *also* change the call to pass `(void*)&t`, not just `(void*)t` - this changes the call to pass t's address, not t's value.